# Xtext Import an existing ecore model

Tags: xtext

I am generating an xtext project from an existing Ecore model and generating a Grammar for it. But in the Grammar file[.Xtext] we are getting an error as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure that

- the plugin containing the ecore has xtext nature
- is on the classpath of the mydsl project

Comment: Can you expound on this?  I am having same issue, but can't figure out how to do either of these in Eclipse.

Comment: (a) right click on project configure convert to Xtext project. (B) edit manifest.mf in Xtext project and add ecore containing project to dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I solved it by

- right-clicking on the project that contains the ecore model you want to import: right-click >> Configure >> Convert to Xtext project

  - and by adding the project to my projects build path: right-click >> Properties >> Java Build Path >> Projects >> Add.. >> and then you just choose the project that contains the model you want to import.

Nevertheless I have a remaining problem caused by the workflow in the generator.